# Strange baking behavior

Tags: texture-baking

When the light is attached to the object, the baking process renders the light but just by separating the light from the object a little the light is not baked in the texture.

What's going on?

[image: separated light]

[image: without separating]

[See video (youtube)](https://youtu.be/-QnPPh116fE)

Blender file for testing attached

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Got it! The normal of the face is inverted

[image]